# How do I get my R buffer in emacs to occupy more horizontal space?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

At the moment when I start up an ESS buffer (with M-x R) I get that the output of my commands only occupies about 60ish characters in column width (particularly when displaying data frames with long column names). I was wondering if there was a simple way to adjust this limit.

Comment: Don't know, but does `options("width")` help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ben Bolker's comment is correct:  `options("width"=200)` is something I use on a machine with wide monitors.

I am not aware of an environment variable that reports this back to ESS to auto-adjust.  It would be a useful addition.

And just like `options("width")`, a few things are generally useful at startup, so I currently have this on another machine

```
edd@max:~$ cat .Rprofile
## Example of .Rprofile
options(width=155, digits=6, digits.secs=6)
## AER page vii
options(prompt="R> ")
## Default repo
local({r <- getOption("repos")
       r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.r-project.org"
       options(repos=r)
})
```

Comment: Oh hey again Dirk! Awesome, what does AER page vii stand for in your second option? Just curious..

Comment: I'm guessing "Applied Econometrics with R" (google hit number 1 on "AER R books")

Comment: :-)  Ben and Google guessed right; the book by Achim and Christian uses that for its code examples and it grew on me.

Answer (score 7):

The following sets R's option "width" to the width of your buffer right on R's startup:

```
(add-hook 'ess-R-post-run-hook 'ess-execute-screen-options)
```

Note that this works with the newest ESS 12.09, for older versions use `ess-post-run-hook`.

Also in the latest ESS you can execute this with <kbd>C-c h</kbd> w <kbd>RET</kbd>, or alternatively bind it to a handy key:

```
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map "\C-cw" 'ess-execute-screen-options)
```

It could be set to execute each time the window changes it's size, but my guess is that it would require quite some lisping.

Comment: sweet! That's useful as well.

Comment: If there's ever a solution that allows it to be executed every time the window changes size, it would be so good! That's the default behavior in RStudio as well.